# removing or clearing stack of popd/pushd paths

Tags: bash, pushd

After `pushd`ing too many times, I want to clear the whole stack of paths.

How would I `popd` all the items in the stack?

I'd like to `popd` without needing to know how many are in the stack?

The bash manual doesn't [seem to cover this](http://ss64.com/bash/popd.html).

Why do I need to know this? I'm fastidious and to clean out the stack.

Comment: BTW, the [complete bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) is over at gnu.org.  If you use the all on one page version, it may be easier to find stuff there.

Comment: Ah wish google indexed that one. Thanks @jw013

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`dirs -c` is what you are looking for.

Comment: this *does* empty the stack, but does *not* restore the working directory from the stack bottom

Answer (score 11):

In order to both empty the stack *and* restore the working directory from the stack bottom, either:

- retrieve that directory from `dirs`, change to that directory, and than clear the stack:

  ```sh
  cd "$(dirs -l -0)" && dirs -c
  ```

  The `-l` option here will list full paths, to make sure we don't fail if we try to `cd` into `~`, and the `-0` retrieves the first entry from the stack bottom.

  @jw013 suggested making this command more robust, by avoiding path expansions:

  ```sh
  pushd -0 && dirs -c
  ```
- or, `popd` until you encounter an error (which is the status of a `popd` call when the directory stack is empty):

  ```sh
  while (( $? == 0 )); do popd; done
  ```

Comment: The first method is exactly what I wanted. The second wouldn't work in my case since I had called `pushd` a few times, then removed one of the directories in the middle, then `popd` was failing when I tried to unroll. I needed to jump over all the buggered up stuff in the middle to get back to where I started.

Comment: right @ChuckWilbur - if you scrambled the dir stack, `popd` won't save you :)

Comment: It's better to `pushd -0` instead of `cd "$(dirs ...)"`.

Comment: @jw013 how so? that would mess with the dir stack even more (which we're trying to clear here..)

Comment: The last step is to clear it (`dirs -c`) so you are left with an empty stack, so it does not matter unless I misunderstood your question.

Comment: fair enough, just asking why is that necessary, or, how is that "better"?

Comment: `cd "$(...)"` works in 90%, probably even 99% of use cases, but with `pushd -0` you can confidently say 100%. There are so many potential gotchas and edge cases associated with expanding file/directory paths in the shell that the most robust thing to do is just avoid it altogether, which `pushd -0` does very concisely. There is no chance of getting caught by a bug with a weird edge case if you never take the risk. If you want further reading on the possible headaches involved with Unix file / path names, a good starting point is http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: awesome! thanx for elaborating