# removing duplicates from pushd/popd paths

Tags: bash, pushd

### Context

- linux bash
- pushd/popd/dirs

### Problem

The problem scenario is very similar to the one stated in this question: [removing or clearing stack of popd/pushd paths](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31248) ... however the goal is not to clear the stack, but rather to *prune* it. Specifically, the pruning operation is to remove duplicates.

### Question

Is there a straightforward way to prune the output of `dirs -v -p` such that there are no duplicates in the stack?

Comment: In zsh, `setopt pushd_ignore_dups` makes this systematic.

Comment: @Gilles: yeah, all the cool kids keep telling me to use zsh ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function should remove dups.

```
dedup(){
    declare -a new=() copy=("${DIRSTACK[@]:1}")
    declare -A seen
    local v i
    seen[$PWD]=1
    for v in "${copy[@]}"
    do if [ -z "${seen[$v]}" ]
       then new+=("$v")
            seen[$v]=1
       fi
    done
    dirs -c
    for ((i=${#new[@]}-1; i>=0; i--))
    do      builtin pushd -n "${new[i]}" >/dev/null
    done
}
```

It copies the list of dirs, except the first which is bogus, into an array `copy`, and for each dir adds it to a `new` array if we have not already `seen` it (an associative array). This ensures older dup entries, which are later in the array, are not copied.
The dir list is cleared, and the array is then `pushd` in reverse order.

The first bogus element of the dirs list is the current directory, which is unchanged. It is set in the `seen` array at the start to also get it removed if earlier in the dir list.

If you want to do this automatically, you can override `pushd` eg:

```
pushd(){
    builtin pushd "$@"
    dedup
}
```

Comment: I suggest adding double quotes around `$PWD` and `$v`, in case you have directory names with spaces in them (lamentably common on some systems).

Comment: It doesn't seem to be necessary with bash in the particular case of an index in `array[index]=...`, but you are right that in general you should double-quote variables, and there is no harm in doing so in this case.

Comment: Also, in your `pushd()` function, the builtin `pushd` command prints the directory stack. In this case, it will print the stack *before* it's de-duplicated. Suggested change: `pushd() { builtin pushd "$@" >/dev/null ; dedup ; dirs ; }` (not tested).